# How to compute integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^{2})}{1+x^{2}} \ dx$ by using complex analysis method.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Consider the integral $$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^{2})}{1+x^{2}}   \ dx
\end{align*}$$
Let $$\begin{align*}
f(z) = \frac{\ln(1+z^{2})}{1+z^{2}}
\end{align*}$$
I want to compute this integral by using residue. Since the integrand has no singularity on $\mathbb{R}$ , I consider the contour:

[image]
Then we have $$\begin{align*}
\left( \int_{-R}^{R}  + \int_{\gamma_{1}} + \int_{\psi_{1}} + \int_{\gamma_{\rho} -} + \int_{\psi_{2}} + \int_{\gamma_{2}}  \right)  \frac{\ln(1+z^{2})}{1+z^{2}} \ dz = 0
\end{align*}$$ since there's no singularity inside the contour.

Then I think I can estimate that  $$\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{R\to \infty} \int_{\gamma_{1}}   \frac{\ln(1+z^{2})}{1+z^{2}} \ dz =0
\end{align*}$$ and $$\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{R \to \infty}  \int_{\gamma_{2}}  \frac{\ln(1+z^{2})}{1+z^{2}} \ dz =0 
\end{align*}$$ and $$\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{\rho\to 0} \int_{\gamma_{\rho}} \frac{\ln(1+z^{2})}{1+z^{2}} \ dz  =0
\end{align*}$$
Thus, we only need to consider the integration on $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{2}$.

Since $\pm i$ are branch point of $\ln(1+z^{2})$ . I define that $$\begin{align*}
\arg(z-i) \in   \left( \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{5\pi}{ 2} \right)  
\\ \arg(z+i) \in   \left( -\frac{\pi}{2} , \frac{3\pi }{2} \right) 
\end{align*}$$ Then on $\psi_{1}$ , we have $$\begin{align*}
\int_{\psi_{1}} \frac{\ln|1+z^{2}| + i (\arg(z-i)+ \arg(z+i)  )}{1+z^{2}} \ dz  = \int_{\psi_{1}} \frac{\ln|1+z^{2}|}{1+z^{2}} \ dz + \int_{\psi_{1}} \frac{3\pi i}{1+z^{2}} \ dz
\end{align*}$$ and $$\begin{align*}
\int_{\psi_{2}} \frac{\ln|1+z^{2}| + i (\arg(z-i)+ \arg(z+i)  )}{1+z^{2}} \ dz  = \int_{\psi_{2}} \frac{\ln|1+z^{2}|}{1+z^{2}}  \ dz+\int_{\psi_{2}} \frac{\pi i}{1+z^{2}} \ dz
\end{align*}$$
Since $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{2}$ has opposite direction, we have the sum will be $$\begin{align*}
-2\pi i\int_{\psi_{2}} \frac{1}{1+z^{2}} \ dz 
\end{align*}$$ where $z=iy$ . Thus, we only need to consider $$\begin{align*}
-2\pi i \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+(iy)^{2}} i\  dy
\end{align*}$$ However, the integral $$\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dy}{1-y^{2}}
\end{align*}$$ is not convergent.

What goes wrong here? Any help on this? Or can you just post the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the answer is probably $2\pi \ln 2$, for what it's worth.

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^{2})}{1+x^{2}}\ dx=2\Re\,\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1-ix)}{1+x^{2}}   \ dx$$
and then you close the contour in the upper half-plane, where $\ln(1-ix)$ does not have branch points.

Comment: To be a bit more rigorous, you can parameterize $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ into their real and imaginary components by using [this contour and how I defined their sets](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w7rqa5x9gs). Hopefully, this might help you figure out where you went wrong. Also, I would define $\arg(z-i) \in   \left( -\frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{ 2} \right)$ and $\arg(z+i) \in   \left( -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{ 2} \right)$ so that $\arg(1+z^2)$ always equals $0$ for all real $z$.